# ¿Cómo es que Google Chrome sabe mi ubicación en Google Maps usando mi PC de escritorio?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-chrome

Por ejemplo al entrar a la página de [Domino's](https://ordena.dominos.com.mx/) pide permiso para obtener la ubicación y me sorprendí porque es muy preciso.

Comment: te lo pongo como comentario, lo que usa en palabras simples usa es la triangulacion para ello emplea la wifi o su señal obtenida sea mendiante repetidores  de su provedor de internet ect... luego usa la recopilacion de coordenadas GPS de alguna bd, cuantas mas redes wifi alrededor o por ejemplo conexiones de usuarios Android que usan el GPS para algun servicio y estos datos han sido almacenados mejor sera para calcular su posicion mas exacta, esto es una manera simple para entender el concepto espero ayude. Saludos

Comment: es decir, busca en un db de referencias cercanas a tu posicion y asi deduce tu ubicacion. la cual, ojo, no es 100% exacta

Answer (score 24, accepted):

La respuesta simple es:

> Utiliza la posición conocida de los puntos de acceso WiFi que son visibles por tu PC de escritorio para triangular **tu** posición.

Pero esta respuesta lleva a otra pregunta:

- ¿Cómo sabe Google la posición geográfica de los puntos de acceso WiFi?.

Bueno, ciertamente utilizan diferentes fuentes, pero primero déjame aclarar que todas ellas alimentan continuamente un sistema que consolida todos los datos y crea el mapa de geolocalización de las redes WiFi. Este mapa es el que tu PC consulta para conocer tu ubicación.

Estas son algunas fuentes bien conocidas:

1. **Dispositivos con Android:** Cuanto activas el GPS de un equipo con Android, este cuenta con información valiosa. La posición geográfica y su precision mas la lista de puntos de acceso WiFi y torres celulares en rango de alcance (incluida la intensidad de la señal). Bajo estas condiciones, el equipo Android envía reportes anónimos (sin información acerca del usuario) a Google Maps. Esta información se añade al sistema.
2. **GOOGLE’S FLEET:** La Flota Google, la misma que toma las fotografías de Google Street View, a medida que recorre ciudades y caminos, va realizando un revelamiento de puntos de acceso WiFi y alimenta el sistema.

Posiblemente tengan otras fuentes, como de equipos portátiles que incluyan receptor GPS. Estos también pueden aportar información al sistema.

**Notas:**

- Si cambias el nombre de un punto de acceso WiFi y le agregas el sufijo "_nomap" (ej. se llama ***GermanWifi*** y la renombras como ***GermanWiFi_nomap***) este punto de acceso se retira del mapa y no es utilizado por google.
- Esta practica no es exclusividad de Google. Apple y Microsoft hacen lo mismo con sus respectivas plataformas mobile.

Comment: Advierto que, los proveedores de Internet, fijan a las direcciones de IP (que tambien tienen nombres de dominio temporales) la locación en coordenadas del modem. Para mas información mirar esto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOC_record

Comment: GOOGLE’S FLEET no es ilegal??